# Modulus simplification $(mn) \bmod d = ab$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I have a modulus question that needs me too prove whether two different statements are true or false.

The information I have been given is that:
\begin{align}
m \bmod d &= a\\
n \bmod d &= b\\
\end{align}
\begin{align}
m &= dk+a\\
n &= dl+b
\end{align}

(..where $k,l,$ and $d$ are integers, with $d>0$.)

I need to demonstrate that $(dkdl-dkb-adl+ab) \bmod d = ab$ by using $(mn)\mod d = ab$.  However, I am unsure on how to simplify the LHS.

I also need to show why $(mn) \bmod d = (ab) \bmod d.$

Answer (score 2):

For any set of integers $a,b,m,n,d$
 $$m\equiv a\pmod d, n\equiv b\pmod d$$

$$\implies mn-ab=m\underbrace{(n-b)}_{\text{ divisible by }d}+b\underbrace{(m-a)}_{\text{ divisible by }d}\equiv0\pmod d$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: note that $d \equiv 0 \pmod{d}$.  Thus, any term like $dkdl \equiv 0\cdot k\cdot 0 \cdot l\equiv 0 \pmod{d}$

Does this help simplify $dkdl-dkb-adl+ab \pmod{d}$?

Comment: But the question states that d > 0?

Comment: @puddles25 That is correct--$d$ should be greater than $0$.  But, when working with modular equivalences, we are concerned with the *remainder* of the expression.  That is, $d\equiv 0 \pmod{d}$ (for *any* $d$), simply because the remainder of $d$ when divided by itself is $0$.